# Why does Flow allow this unsound destructuring assignment?

Tags: flowtype

https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHdQGcAuAnAlgYxQKC7AHaqgDaaApkgK7QoC6oAvKAN4AeAXKAIwC+AbiA

Flow reports no errors on this code:

```
// @flow strict
const [result] = {x: 1};
```

But when I try to execute it I get: `Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)} is not iterable`.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in flow or if I'm just misunderstanding something.

---

Perhaps Flow is thinking the above is equivalent to

```
const result = {x: 1}[0];
```

Which I know flow intentionally allows to pass typechecking because it's an array access. In this case, `result` is `undefined` rather than a TypeError being thrown.

Comment: There's a github issue for this here: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7859

Comment: @LyleUnderwood ah I missed that, thank you!